# Webpage scraping using rvest package and selectorgadget tool in r

Tags: r, web-scraping, css-selectors, rvest

I am trying to scrape the Baltic Panamax Index data from a site. I have scraped data from other sites as well but its not working for this page. 
I am using an office connection whereas the site to be downloaded from shows 'Not Secure' connection. Is that causing an issue?

I require the "Date" and the "Close" column and have written the following code for scraping as of now:

```
#Baltic Panamax Index
#Specifying the url for desired website to be scraped
con=url("http://marine-transportation.capitallink.com/indices/baltic_exchange_history.html?ticker=BPI","rb")

#Reading the HTML code from the website
webpage <- read_html(con)
webpage

#Using CSS selectors to scrape the date section*
date_data = html_nodes(webpage,".text .div_line:nth-child(2)")

#Converting the ranking data to text
date_data <- html_text(date_data)

#Let's have a look at the rankings*
head(date_data)
```

**Output required:**

```
Date          Close
Jan 03,2020   949
Jan 02,2020   1003
```

Comment: I think the website requires login credentials to see the data.

Comment: Yes, credentials are required but how should the form be made? I am getting the following error: "Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Could not resolve host: marine-transportation.capitallink.com"

Answer (score 0):

You need to send your user name as a cookie in the request header to get this page. I find the `httr` package gives great flexibility to make such requests. For this site, you will need to use the user name you have already registered with the site. Just change the `user_name` field in the code below and this should work for you:

```r
# Use the httr package to allow flexibility with http requests
library(httr)
library(rvest)

# Set username here -----
#                       |
#             ---------------------
#             |                   |
#             v                   v
user_name  <- "my.name@example.com"

# Set url we need
site  <- "http://marine-transportation.capitallink.com"
url   <- paste0(site, "/indices/baltic_exchange_history.html?ticker=BPI")

# Obtain the page we want using user name as a cookie
response <- GET(url, set_cookies(clUser_email = user_name,
                                 expires      = "Sat, 16-Sep-2051 11:30:30 GMT",
                                 `Max-Age`    = "1000000000",
                                 path         = "/",
                                 domain       = "capitallink.com"))

# Parse the HTML code from the website using rvest
webpage       <- read_html(response)
date_data     <- html_nodes(webpage, "table")
result        <- html_table(date_data[4])[[1]]

# Tidy up the result
result        <- result[-1, 2:3]
names(result) <- c("Date", "Close")
```

Now we have the result you were looking for:

```r
result
#>            Date   Close
#> 2  Jan 06, 2020  890.00
#> 3  Jan 03, 2020  949.00
#> 4  Jan 02, 2020 1003.00
#> 5  Dec 24, 2019 1117.00
#> 6  Dec 23, 2019 1154.00
#> 7  Dec 20, 2019 1201.00
#> 8  Dec 19, 2019 1265.00
#> 9  Dec 18, 2019 1340.00
# ....[ plus 50 more rows]....
```

Comment: Hi Allan, thanks so much for the code but I am still facing the issue where I keep getting the error "Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Could not resolve host: marine-transportation.capitallink.com". I looked for the solution "https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1996" but I am not sure whether its going to solve or not.

Comment: Ami - where are you getting the error? Are you changing the code so that your username replaces "my.name@example.com"? As you can see, it worked for me with my username (not the example one given in the code obviously)